# Why do Boxes created in a spawned thread have stack addresses?

Tags: multithreading, rust, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

### Question

When a `Box` is created in a spawned thread, the address of the `Box` is very high, which is typical of stack addresses, but a `Box` should point to the heap. Why is the address so high?

### Code

```rust
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let x = 42;

    println!("x (main thread, stack):     {:p}", &x);
    println!("Box (main thread, heap):    {:p}", Box::new(x));

    thread::spawn(|| {
        let x = 42;

        println!("x (spawned thread, stack):  {:p}", &x);
        println!("Box (spawned thread, heap): {:p}", Box::new(x));
    });

    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)); // Give the spawned thread some time
}
```

### Output

```
x (main thread, stack):     0x7fff1d0cb414
Box (main thread, heap):    0x55e608db8ae0
x (spawned thread, stack):  0x7f94ae707b54
Box (spawned thread, heap): 0x7f94a8000b80
```

### Environment

- Linux
- cargo 1.69.0
- rustc 1.69.0

Comment: I can't find any reference for it, but I could imagine that Rust partitions the heap between threads to reduce allocator contention. That could explain why the two heap addresses are so far apart.

Answer (score 1):

The second pair of addresses is [103 MiB](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%280x7f94ae707b54-0x7f94a8000b80%29+Bytes+in+MiB) apart, well beyond the [2 MiB Stack size of spawned threads](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/index.html#stack-size) so neither of the boxes allocates anywhere near any of the stacks. Apart from that the exact memory locations are implementation details.

Comment: 103MiB is 5 _orders of magnitude_ smaller than the [4.414×10^7 MiB](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%280x7fff1d0cb414-0x55e608db8ae0%29+Bytes+in+MiB) difference between the previous two stack and heap addresses, though. Why is the difference so vast?